# Batch clip returning a single raster only

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, clip, batch

I am trying to use a batch clip over a few of my raster layers in ArcGIS. After inputting the multiple layers, I receive only a single output image corresponding to one of the input files. I checked the inputs before pressing OK. No error messages after as well. The application just clips one and then leaves it.
What do I do?

Comment: You need to add way more information. Show how you ran you batch processing, as python or as batch mode? Parameter settings etc.

Comment: Yep, take a screenshot of the batch processing tool with parameters filled out.